# Proof of index number in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

Pictures above show the lemma and its proof in my complex analysis course. My question is how do we know we need to define $h$ to be in that form? Because when I try to prove the lemma on my own, I can't get anywhere.

Comment: Well, I guess this case is like many others: along years and years people tries this, tries that, takes a little from here and a little from there until a more or less neat development is reached...Personally, this is one of the shortest, neatest and most beautiful proofs of this theorem I've ever seen.

Comment: Yikes! I downvoted your question @Idonknow... **by mistake** ! I didn't even notice I clicked there. Undone and upvoted.

Comment: BTW @Idonknow: from what book is this proof?

Comment: This is my course lecture note. I think the proof is thought by my prof because I can't seem to find this proof in any complex analysis book.

Comment: Do you have a link where to download this lecture notes from? I'd appreciate if you can write it down. It looks like a book...

Comment: @DonAntonio That proof is classical. It's almost verbatim the proof Ahlfors gives. (Also `@`Idonknow, it's not by your prof, I'm sure, he's certainly not that old ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by definition $$\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{\gamma(t)-z_0}=\int_a^b\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-z_0}\mathrm dt,$$
so it seems not *too* unnatural to consider the right hand side as a function of $b$.

The much trickier part is to come up with the invariant $e^{-h(t)}(\gamma(t)-z_0)$ from the equation $h'(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-z_0}$, but then again after straightforward reordering to $h'(t)\cdot(\gamma(t)-z_0)-\gamma'(t)=0$ this almost calls for viewing this as the result of the product rule, i.e. the derivative of some $f(t)(\gamma(t)-z_0)$. However, since this is rather $f'(t)(\gamma(t)-z_0)+\gamma'(t)f(t)$ we need to look for $f$ such that $h=-\frac{f'}{f}=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\ln f(t)$, so take $f(t)=e^{-h(t)}$.

Comment: IMHO this is more apparent if you set $z_0=0$.